# chrome extension: evernote webclipper slowing down each click by around 1s

Tags: google-chrome, evernote

i thought my page i develop loads a bit slow (it really doesn't) but I had a quick look.

I saw this:

[image]

domready at around 1.5 seconds finish at 1.6, 1.7 seconds

note the piece of timeline i have selected. Those is all coming from evernote web clipper.

I disabled evernote webclipper and reloaded a couple times, the times stay roughly like so:

[image]

the result is a bit a surprise. Pretty much half the load time with finish at around 800 ms.

First of all, i like evernote, but is it worth waiting at least a second on each page (note, this page was kind of simple)?

is there a way to speed up evernote or to easily with shortcut combo enable disable it?
i use it rarely, but when i want to use it i don't want to have to browse through 10 menus.